# Containable "contain" property not being reset

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, containable

Containable is not behaving as I expect in CakePHP 2.1.2 in the following code:

```
class ReportCard extends AppModel {

....
    // debug shows expected results
    public function test1(){
        $this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        $params = array(
                'conditions' => array('ReportCard.id' => 1),
                'contain' => array(
                        'ReportCardGradingPeriodCollection' => array(
                                'GradingPeriodCollection')));

        debug($this->find('first', $params));
        $this->Behaviors->detach('Containable');
    }

    // Unexpected: debug shows same array as test1
    public function test2(){
        $this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        $params = array(
                'conditions' => array('ReportCard.id' => 1),
                'contain' => array(
                        'ReportCardGradingPeriodCollection' => array(
                                'GradingPeriodCollection' => array(
                                        'GradingPeriodCollectionDetail' => array(
                                                'GradingPeriod')))));

        debug($this->find('first', $params));
        $this->Behaviors->detach('Containable');
    }

}
```

I get unexpected results when calling the functions from the controller. `test1()` shows the expected array. `test2()` shows the same array from `test1`. If I run `test2()` then `test1()` I get expected results (large array, then small array).

```
class ReportCardsController extends AppController {

    ....

    public function test(){
        $this->ReportCard->test1();
        $this->ReportCard->test2();
    }

}
```

I have tried using `actAs` in the model instead of dynamically loading the behavior in each function, but that did not help.

I apologize if I'm missing something simple. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the manual:

> Containable must to be attached to all models used in containment,

From your example code it's not clear whether you are doing that.

And here's the remaining half of that note:

> you may consider attaching it to your AppModel.

Comment: I placed `public $actsAs = array('Containable');` in `AppModel`. This did not help.